# Negative Lookahead for 2 numbers after decimal

Tags: regex

I need to have a regex that only matches everything that isn't formatted as

NOT selected

> 222.22
>
> 22.22
>
> 2.22

anything that is text or just a number should be selected.

SELECTED

> text
>
> 22.2 222
>
> 22.22222

I tried this since it seems logical but nothing, is there a regex that will work for what I want?

```
^(?!\d+\.\d{0,2})$
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like what you're selecting is better defined than what you're not.

Is your input nicely tokenized already or are you searching a big paragraph of text?

```
^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$
```

If so just get a logical out of that and flip it with NOT and filter